# My capslock key is taking screenshots and saving them to my Public Pictures folder

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, virus, capslock

So today while playing Borderlands 2, my SSD popped up and said that there is no enough space.
At first I did not understand what was going on, but after investigating a bit, I found thousands of pictures in a .bmp format in the `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Screenshots` folder.
The pictures carry names in the following format: "Desktop_2012_09_22_03_29_02_247.bmp"
And after investigating some more, it seems like my caps lock is responsible for that.
Any ideas why my caps lock is taking screenshots and saving them automatically in the public folder in a .bmp format?

I thought it was a virus, scanned with MalwareBytes/ESET online/AVG/SpyBot, and I seem to be clean.

Comment: Are the screenshots all from the same application?  If so, it might be that application.

Answer (score 1):

What are the screenshots of, the game or something else? If the former, check the game's key bindings. You might have accidentally set Caps Lock as the key for saving screenshots of the action.

However, if pressing the key without running any program still results in a screenshot being saved, check your Task Manager's Processes list and your installed programs list to see whether you can identify the culprit.

Edit: Since Steam's F12 seems to be the way to save screenshots of the game, run [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html) and see if you've previously remapped your Caps Lock key to F12.

Comment: I have turned every piece of software I could come up with, and checked the latest installed ones...do not think that any of them are doing it. I also installed the SharpKeys software and re-bound capslock, and still the same issue.

Comment: So is it a global hotkey, or does it do this only inside the game?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a different key (arrow key) and eventually tracked it down to **MSI Afterburner**, which is a small application to control the clock speed of your graphics card. It puts them in exactly this (slightly unusual) location: `\Users\Public\Pictures\Screenshots`

In the Afterburner settings, there is a tab called *Screen capture*, which allows you to set up a key to capture screenshots in any application. Click on the box with the key listed and press **backspace**, and it should update the value to *None*. This will stop the screenshots.

There's nothing wrong with Afterburner, and it's not malicious or spyware: it's just a setting that might get turned on that you maybe don't want.

(BTW, [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) is an amazing and free tool for finding out why your hard drive is so full.)